# Sending email with attachment using Cygwin email package

Tags: batch-file

I installed cygwin together with this package: https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/email/email-3.2.1-git-1

Do you know how to create a bat file and send email with attachment using cygwin email package in windows 10?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in [`powershell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373405/how-to-send-email-to-distribution-list-in-outlook-using-task-scheduler)?

Comment: ohh okay okay I didn't know about this. Ill check this one, thank you

Comment: I have sent an email using powershell, however can I do this using a batch file? So that a user is only one click away? @Gerhard

Comment: either wrap the `powershell` command in `batch-file` or simply save the content of the powershell script as `send_email.ps1` then in the batch file do `powershell .\send_email.ps1` obviously either specify full path to the `ps1` file or put it in the same directory as the `batch-file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Powershell` is builtin to your windows device,`powershell 2.0` and up has the `Send-MailMessage` function. If you really need to use `batch-file` for this task, you can simply call `powershell` from within a `batch-file`:

```
@echo off
powershell Send-MailMessage -From 'someone@someserver.net' -To 'recipient@address.com' -Subject 'Test email' -Body 'This is a test' -SmtpServer mailserver.domain.com -Attachments 'C:\Some Dir\Somefile.txt'
```

to break it down into a readable form on Stackoverlow:

```
powershell Send-MailMessage 
      -From 'someone@someserver.net'
      -To 'recipient@address.com'
      -Subject 'Test email'
      -Body 'This is a test'
      -SmtpServer mailserver.domain.com
      -Attachments 'C:\Some Dir\Somefile.txt'
```

Comment: for this one, i tried this as well but it is asking to supply values and didn't automatically send though...

Comment: Which paramaters is it asking for? You need to fill in all the fields where I used examples. Also use the first one and not the second example. The second is purely to display it in a more readable way.

Comment: Nvm. I used your first recommendation thank you so much!