# Combine PowerShell Defender outlets into a combined CSV file for monitoring

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, monitoring, windows-defender

We cancelled our antivirus software ([Kaspersky Anti-Virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaspersky_Anti-Virus), duh) and depend on the [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender) in the meantime.

We won’t be getting any [SIEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_information_and_event_management) server to log and monitor all our Agents Defender Status, so I'm trying to make my life a bit easier by writing a .bat file that combines two PowerShell commands and exports the findings into a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

```
Get-MpThreatDetection; Get-MPcomputerstatus | Select-Object -First 4 | Export-Csv c:\WindowsDefender.csv -notypeinformation -useculture
```

I know it’s kind of wonky as it stands, but the main goals are to:

1. Have the current (and last) updated version of the Defender that is being shown by `Get-MPComputerstatus`
2. Have the last four incidents being shown in full via the PowerShell command `Get-MpThreatDetection`

They both work well independently, but I'm just lost with the task to combine them and in the end, have the wanted information formatted for me in [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel).

On top of that, I'd finish it off with an automated email towards me and other support team members. Something along the lines of

```
$file = "c:\WindowsDefender.csv"
$smtpServer = "The smtp.server.com that is needed"
$att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "WindowsDefender@Business.com"
$msg.To.Add("Email@Domain.com")
$msg.Subject = "Win-Defender Update MSG"
$msg.Body = "Attached is the ServerName Security Logs report"
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()
```

Obviously, the last part would happen when I combine all the CSV files together in the end in a single directory, so that I can get a full overview of our 60+ PCs.

Is this even possible? Am I daydreaming? Spending money for IT at our company is a no-no for now, so I won’t be getting any other chance to monitor Defender on all our clients :(

*Update*: After working around for a while I changed my approach a bit and am using now the `Get-WinEvent` to filter those out. It works well with:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
logname="Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational";id=1116,1117,2000}|`
Where-Object { $_.LevelDisplayName -ne "Information" } |`
Select-Object Message,ID,Level,Logname,MachineName,timecreated |`
Export-Csv c:\windowsdefender.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

But the issue is that the "Message" tab has all the information I want, but it’s all clumped together under "Messages" and is not formatted as it should be.

Comment: Would be helpful to us if you can show us an example of what the combined csv file would look like; a.k.a, the finished result.

Comment: It would look something like this:

https://imgur.com/a/fwlJbiV

It doesnt have to show all the last threats, just the last would suffice. So in the end I would get a list of the current versions of defender, and when the last issue seemed to be (if any at all)

Comment: It is very possible yes, but a bit broad. It classifies as a code request. What I would have done instead would be to create a simple http server, pipe all the results to the server and publish it as html. you can simply access the html and export if needed. I have done these types of things numerous times. Anyway, have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373405/how-to-send-email-to-distribution-list-in-outlook-using-task-scheduler) on emailing a file using powershell.